# Simplify $ch(\mathcal{O}(1))td(\mathbb{P}^n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-space

Let $\mathcal{O}(1)\to \mathbb{P}^n$ be the the inverse of the tautological bundle over the projective space. Denote by $td(\mathbb{P}^n)$ the Todd class of the tangent bundle to $\mathbb{P}^n$. Can we simplify the expression
$$ch(\mathcal{O}(1))td(\mathbb{P}^n) ?$$

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you mean by 'simplify'? Both $\operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(1))$ and $\operatorname{Td}(\mathbb{CP}^n)$ can be written in terms of Chern classes of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and $T\mathbb{CP}^n$ respectively; is this what you mean? Also, is your goal to calculate $\chi(\mathbb{CP}^n, \mathcal{O}(1))$ using the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch Theorem?

Comment: I meant that both factors could be expressed in terms of $c_1(O(1))$ so that we should be able to get some polynomial of $c_1(O(1))$. I just get a bit confused with the computations

Comment: Well $\operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(1)) = e^x$ and $\operatorname{Td}(\mathbb{CP}^n) = \left(\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}\right)^{n+1}$, but I'm not sure if you can simplify the product.